# Customize Log out page for a sub-site

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, login, sub-site

Is there a way to log a user out of a sharepoint subsite and redirect them to a page different from the root site?

I've searched far and wide, tried quite a bit and I still cannot figure out a way to do achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: You can only have a customized sign out page configured at web application level instead of subsite level

Comment: @FalakMahmood how about a redirect?

Comment: Well, you could also configure IIS7 URL rewrite redirect or write a httpmodule. The former is easy to implement.

Comment: @FalakMahmood yeap thats the most reasonable solution :)

Comment: Would you mind marking this question as answered if I post it an answer?

Comment: @FalakMahmood gladly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could also configure IIS7 URL rewrite redirect or write a httpmodule. The former is easy to implement.

Comment: :D there you go